# Is there a way to pass a local that is item dependent when rendering a collection rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have below line as the last statement in my controller action:

```
render json: {
      html: render_to_string(
        partial: "_item_content.html.haml",
        collection: items, as: :item,
        locals: {
          seller: @seller
      }, layout: false),
      is_last_page: items.last_page?
    }
```

In my partial I am doing `item_discount = item.eligible_discount_for(current_user)` which is what I want to avoid.

Is there a way to compute and pass `eligible_discount` as a local for each `item` while rendering the partial in the controller action? If not, how can I refactor this so I don't have to do the `item_discount = item.eligible_discount(current_user)` computation in the partial.

Comment: Please paste the code of the partial otherwise it's impossible to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I had to finish this quickly, below is what I did to keep the partial a bit cleaner and do the computation in the action, though I am not really sure it's the best way. Basically, instead of passing the collection to render, changed it to loop over the collection and aggregate the individual strings. Posting in case anyone else finds this useful, or can provide feedback to improve.

```
items_html = items.map do |item|
  eligible_discount = item.eligible_discount_for(current_user)
  render_to_string(partial: "item_content.html.haml",
                   locals: {
                     item: item,
                     seller: @seller,
                     eligible_discount: eligible_discount
                   },
                   layout: false)
end.reduce("", :+)

render json: {
  html: items_html,
  is_last_page: items.last_page?
}
```